# Intellij plugin development - Get access to internal stack of last activated editors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In an intellij plugin development environment I would like to access what should be available some kind of stack over what editors was last activated.

I believe this is use by **"activate most recently opened file"**.

Building this index myself would lead to mistakes due to various ways to open a file/tab.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development would be the best place for such questions.

Comment: I think i've implemented a working solution although based on EditorHistoryManager which normally will include all history of active files, but by checking if they are open, i can get around it. I feel the default CloseAction should already do that, but the code in source is not that readable and no callable method for it it seems.

Comment: I posted the answer. isOpen and project is not part of it but did not want to post the entire code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /**
     * Note, most recent file is last in the list.
     */
    public List<VirtualFile> getRecentFiles() {
            return EditorHistoryManager.getInstance(project).getFileList();
    }
    public VirtualFile getMostRecentFile(int index) {
            return getMostRecentFile(index, true);
    }
    public VirtualFile getMostRecentFile(int index, boolean mustBeOpen) {
            List<VirtualFile> files = getRecentFiles();

            int i = files.size() - index - 1;

            if ( i < files.size() ) {
                    VirtualFile file = files.get(i);

                    if ( mustBeOpen && !isOpen(file) ) {
                            file = getMostRecentFile( index - 1, mustBeOpen );
                    }

                    return file;
            }

            return null;
    }
```

`getMostRecentFile(1)` would get the file prior to currently active editor.

`isOpen` and `project` is missing here but can be retrieved from AnActionEvent event in a couple of ways.